RIP Maggie Smith
The acting legend Dame Maggie Smith has just passed away, at almost 90 years old. Her extensive acting career, starting from 1956 and continuing up to at least 2023, earned her two Oscars, five BAFTAs, four Emmys, three Golden Globes, and a Tony Award - "quite enough to be getting on with", as Professor McGonagall might have said.
May she rest in peace, and let's remember one of her most relatable moments in probably her most widely known role:


+1 She may be better known in later years for McGonagall, but to me she was the best part of Downton Abbey (and of course, she had an illustrious career). She'll be missed.

Don't forget Dora Charleston, the Mother Superior, or that rant…

"At my age, I don’t plan that far ahead. I don’t even buy green bananas." - Maggie Smith in The Best Exotic Marigold Hotel.
